# Portable Asp.Net Software

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, portable-executable

I don't know what words should I use to ask my problem, so now here I am explaining it. I have developed a software using ASP.Net and MySql. Now I want to run that software on a system which has none of the two installed.

So, how to make it possible? Should I need to any property in my application or something else?

Please let me guys... I need it. Thanks in advance friends

Comment: This Exactly what you looking for a Self-Hosted ASP.net application http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750530%28v=vs.110%29.aspx For MySQL I'm sure the native of ASP.Net attached MDF file will suffice

Comment: i am sorry I posted a console application this should do the  work http://nancyfx.org/

Comment: Or this http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your IIS and MySQL seem to be pre-requisites that need to be present and functioning in order to run your application. You can do one of two things;

1. Tell the user to install them (in the case of IIS, turn on the system feature) and provide URLs to documentation telling them how to do it.
2. Wrap the MySQL installer and the instructions to Windows to turn on IIS in your own product installer.

Comment: How the other softwares work which we download from the net. In that we oly download a .exe and thats it. I want to know that process. If some you know something about that

Comment: Ok, I think you really need to read up on how to deploy applications, start with "Deploying .NET Applications Lifecycle Guide" http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913507 and perhaps go onto some sample code like "Deploying ASP.NET Websites on IIS7" http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28693/Deploying-ASP-NET-Websites-on-IIS.

Its such a big topic and your question is so broad that there really isn't "One Answer" but a whole set of techniques you must learn.